# How can one have a theme switcher in primereact

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I would like to be in a position to switch between themes in primereact rather than import one theme and then it affects my whole app and I don't have an option to switch between dark or light mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an even easier way to do this
They do explain it a bit in the docs but it isn't as copy-paste in the docs

Here is what I did in my React app:

This is in my index.html file
Define an element with an id to reference later in your code, and them also href to the directory where the styles are.

```
   <link id="app-theme" rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/lara-dark-blue/theme.css">
```

The styles should be copied from the node_modules of prime react
Copy the dark and light theme from Lara

```
cp -r ./node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/lara-light-blue ./public/themes/lara-light-blue
cp -r ./node_modules/primereact/resources/themes/lara-dark-blue ./public/themes/lara-dark-blue
```

You can also just drag and drop them, but terminal is also nice ;)

Now in your React component, import PrimeReact from the api directory and then use the changeTheme utility function to change from dark to light and vice versa

```
import PrimeReact from 'primereact/api';

function App() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('dark');

  const changeMyTheme = () => {
    const newTheme = theme === 'dark' ? 'light' : 'dark';
    PrimeReact?.changeTheme?.(`lara-${theme}-blue`, `lara-${newTheme}-blue`, 'app-theme', () =>
      setTheme(newTheme)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <header>
        <button
          className={`p-2 rounded ${theme === 'dark' ? 'bg-gray-100 text-black' : 'bg-gray-700 text-white'}`}
          onClick={() => changeMyTheme()}
        >
          <span className={`pr-1 pi pi-${theme === 'dark' ? 'sun' : 'moon'}`}></span>
         Change Theme
        </button>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here are the docs if you need to reference some more details as well as other themes available
https://primereact.org/theming/

Comment: I still couldn't make it work. In the end I just used useeffect and dom manipulation to switch theme. I advise others to do the same.  ` useEffect(() => {
    const link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = `${props.mode}.css`;
    document.head.appendChild(link);
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(link);
    };
  }, [props.mode]);`

Answer (score 6):

Observing how they do it on the website [www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/](https://www.primefaces.org/primereact/showcase/), open Developer view: Elements, and one can notice that choosing a different theme changes css file link in HTML header:

```
<link id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href="./themes/bootstrap4-light-blue/theme.css">
```

becomes

```
<link id="theme-link" rel="stylesheet" href="./themes/bootstrap4-light-purple/theme.css">
```

It is fairly easy to switch link element HREF from one to another.

This page talks about primereact theme switching:
[Switch Your React App Between Material, Bootstrap and Custom Themes at Runtime](https://primetek.hashnode.dev/switch-your-react-app-between-material-bootstrap-and-custom-themes-at-runtime)

But the method it describes is too convoluted, involves ejecting and custom webpack, to bundle all theme CSS files and import them programmatically, like that:

```
const changeTheme = (theme) => {
  import(`./${theme}.scss`).then((module) => {
    if (selectedThemeModule) {
      selectedThemeModule.unuse();
    }
    module.use();
    setSelectedThemeModule(module);
  });
}
```

Instead, grab the example repo where they do method of link HREF swap: [github.com/mertsincan/primereact-dynamic-theming/](https://github.com/mertsincan/primereact-dynamic-theming/)

example-1 has code for the convoluted method from the above page, you can skip it and go to example-2, which is much simpler.

In a nutshell, add to 'public/index.html', in <header> section:

```
<link id="app-theme" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="saga-blue.css">
```

And use this function:

```
const changeTheme = (theme) => {
  let themeLink = document.getElementById('app-theme');
  if (themeLink) {
    themeLink.href = theme + '.css';
  }
}
```

Then just call `changeTheme(XXX)` when theme XXX is clicked.

Next put .css files into the right place - just copy all node_modules/primereact/themes/*/theme.css files into public folder (giving them corresponding theme names). Some theme.css reference fonts - search for "url" in each file, and if present, copy corresponding fonts/ directory too.

I should mention that benefits of example-1 is using minified and bundled CSS files, so themes will be switching faster. If that's important, then follow the above linked tutorial and example-1. Also note that example-2 has very similar setup to example-1 (eject and custom webpack config), but only to copy css files to the right output folder, which can be skipped in favor of copying files by hand once.

Comment: Thank you so much I will check the solution and get back to you as soon as I  can

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make it work with their provided function   https://primereact.org/theming/#switchthemes

I have use `useEffect` for my case which changes theme dark <-> light based on prop.

First I copied the themes I wanted  to the public folder root. I named them `light.css` and `dark.css`. Then in useEffect I manipulated DOM:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const link = document.createElement("link");
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.href = `${props.mode}.css`;
    document.head.appendChild(link);
    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(link);
    };
  }, [props.mode]);
```

Now it works when `props.mode` change from `light` to `dark` and vice versa.